# "jumping effect" with sticky position on newer iOS devices

Tags: css, webkit, sticky

The content of the header element has a "jumping effect" when scrolling. This only happens on iOS mobile devices.

The header has `sticky` position. If I change it to `fixed` position, it fixes the issue, but then the scroll bouncing effect doesn't work well. How is it possible to fix this issue without using fixed position?

[The website with the described problem](https://www.creativefabrica.com/studio/) is online and you can see and edit the CSS by inspecting the website in browser.

[image]

I tried changing the position, setting the width of the child elements in the header, but nothing fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit:

> After further investigation, the issue seems to occur **on newer iOS devices**, such as the iPhone 13 or newer, and *not just* in the simulator, as originally assumed.

One "trick" that has helped me a lot in the past with transition/animation issues in Safari (but sometimes in other browsers too) where things get *shaky* and *jumpy*, is to force the browser to use **"hardware acceleration"** so that the browser also uses **GPU power** instead of just CPU power to render.

There are many articles on this topic because it has been around for a long time, but it is still relevant, and you can read up on it if you are interested in more information:

- [The translateZ Trick by Michael Uloth](https://michaeluloth.com/css-translate-z/)
- [Web Performance fundamentals on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Fundamentals#specific_coding_tips_for_application_performance) mentions this usage too
- [CSS GPU Animation: Doing It Right](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/12/gpu-animation-doing-it-right/)

In your specific case, put the following CSS declaration on the "jumping" SVGs in your sticky header:

```css
transform: translateZ(0);
```

This seems to **stop the "jumping" of the SVGs** in your sticky header when *scrolling* on newer iOS devices.

---

#### Original Answer:

Since I see a mouse cursor on your GIF, I *assume* you tested it with an **iOS simulator**. Is this assumption correct?
If so, this seems to be a **problem/bug in the simulator** (which is a common thing with simulators because they are not 100% accurate and the same as the original OS/device).

I came to this conclusion because testing the sticky positioned header on a *real* iOS device (iOS Version 17 on iPhone 11) does *not* seem to reproduce the unwanted "jumping" effect, as can be seen in the following recording (low-res GIF):

[image: Scrolling in Safari on iOS 17]

Comment: I see this on real device as well. I see this bug on iPhone 13 device, but I don't see it on Android device. What iphone did you try?

Comment: I tested it with the iPhone 11, so I assume this issue occurs on newer iOS devices. I have updated my answer with this information, and I have found a fix for your specific issue, which is also described in the updated answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: amazing! I confirmed you fixed that. I don't understand why I got downvotes :(

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad it worked out for your live site :) Maybe your question is missing [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please feel free to improve your question so that it will be helpful to others in the future.